# Integral form of a telescoping series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to know if the following relation is true

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz  \tanh{\pi z} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-z^2}} \right] = \sum_{n>0} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(n+1/2)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+(n+1/2)^2}} \right]. $$ I will name the last series $S$.
I consider a complex contour that begins in the negative part of the real axis, goes around the points $\pm 1, \pm \sqrt{2}$ with half circle, then closes with a half circle in the upper half plane. The small half circles on the real axis won't give any contribution to the full integral because the residues at $z=\pm 1, \pm \sqrt{2}$ will be zero. Same for the half circle in the upper half plane when we took its radius to be large (the integral for the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ term will be canceled by the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-z^2}}$ term for radius that tends to infinity).
Now the contour enclosed poles of $\tanh{\pi z}$ which are at the points $i(n+1/2)$, $n>0$. By the residue theorem I get that the integral written above $I= 2\pi i S$.

I tried to numerically evaluate $I$ in Mathematica to compare it to the numerical value of $S$. I found significative differences between the two.

So I would like to know if my calculation is flawed.

Comment: Typo? Singularities  of integrand are at $z=\pm \sqrt{2}$. Also did you introduce branch cuts to give meaning to the complex contour integral.?

Comment: @MathWonk Yes it was typos, thanks. I put the branch cuts in the lower half plane. This is not valid ?